# Clear Firebase local write queue yet to sync Manually

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an Android application which uses Firebase Realtime Database to show data to multiple user.

When user start live mode Application start sending data to Firebase, then there may be cases it loses network connectivity and then user stop live mode.

After Stopping Live Mode, I want to make sure no previous data should be synced to Firebase, i.e, Clear out local write queue.

I am not able to find how to clear local write queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, not tried yet.
I think `purgeOutstandingWrites()` will do the trick.