# How can I clear the local write queue yet to sync for Firebase Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on Android application where the user can upload up to nine photos in the grid of image views. When uploading the photo, I am also sending information about which image view in the grid the photo occupies. There should be only one photo information per image view in the Firestore. Once the user triggered photo upload I am making the grid invisible and displaying infinite progress bar instead as to not allow schedule multiple uploads for the same image view.

The problem comes with offline mode of Firestore. The user can try to upload photo, which will schedule write query and keep displaying progress bar. However, in the meantime the user can leave the activity with the grid and come back. It will recreate the grid and the user can then try to upload another photo to the same image view. The user can repeat it over and over scheduling as many writes as the user wants at the moment. I think the simplest solution would be to clear the write queue every time the user leaves the activity and it is destroyed.

Is it possible to do that in the Firestore? I have seen that someone asked similar question for Realtime Database and there exists function there to clear the offline write queue.

[Clear Firebase local write queue yet to sync Manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51746363/clear-firebase-local-write-queue-yet-to-sync-manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the pending writes is not a good solution here.  The [local cache provided by the Firestore SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) isn't a "work queue", and it's not a good idea to work with it like that.  The cache a local copy of data that stays in sync with the data on the server.  If you use the Firestore SDK to write, you should only assume that the write will eventually be synchronized with the server.  It's not a good idea to try to clear that cache while the user is using the app.  If you don't want a write cache at all, then you should consider disabling persistence entirely, as described in the documentation previously linked in this answer.

If you only want the user to be able to do one thing at a time, your app should retain some internal state that remembers and keeps track of the thing already in progress.  Your app's UI should then tell the user they have to wait for that thing to finish.